# validate a user input

Tags: java, regex, string, methods, pattern-matching

Hello I'm new to programming and I'm having a trouble understanding my assignment. I know that this might be a really simple problem for you guys and I'm sorry for that. Is it possible that she's just asking me to write a method that will perform the given instructions?

Write a program to find if the user input is valid base on the instructions.**

1. a string must have at least nine characters
2. a string consists of letters and numbers only.
3. a string must contain at least two digits.

Comment: you need to write a separate method like `public static boolean isValid(String input)`. In that method write code to verify each rule. You can use methods on String class like length(), charAt(int). Also look into [`Character.isDigit(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))

Comment: @onkar ruikar is it ok sir if I ask for a sample code?

Comment: When solving problems like this, attempt each step one at a time.  What does "a string must have at least nine characters" mean? How would you write Java code to check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Requirement #1: a string must have at least nine characters

This is solved by checking whether the length of the String is greater than 9, with `s.length()>9`

#### Requirement #2: a string consists of letters and numbers (whole numbers) only.

Use the regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, which matches all Latin alphabet characters and numbers.

#### Requirement #3: a string must contain at least two digits.

I've written a method that loops through every character and uses `Character.isDigit()` to check whether it is a digit.

Check it out:

```
public static boolean verify(String s) {
    final String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
    System.out.println(numOfDigits(s));
    return s.length() > 9 && s.matches(regex) && numOfDigits(s) > 2;
}

public static int numOfDigits(String s) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        a += (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the regex, `^(?=(?:\D*\d){2})[a-zA-Z\d]{9,}$` which can be explained as follows:

- `^` : asserts position at start of a line
- [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=(?:\D*\d){2})`

  - Non-capturing group `(?:\D*\d){2}`

    ```
    {2} matches the previous token exactly 2 times
    \D matches any character that's not a digit (equivalent to [^0-9])
    * matches the previous token between zero or more time (greedy)
    \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
    ```
- The [pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), `[a-zA-Z\d]{9,}` :

  ```
  {9,} matches the previous token between 9+ times (greedy)
  a-z matches a single character in a-z
  A-Z matches a single character in A-Z
  \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
  ```
- `$` : asserts position at the end of a line

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //Test
        Stream.of(
                    "helloworld",
                    "hello",
                    "hello12world",
                    "12helloworld",
                    "helloworld12",
                    "123456789",
                    "hello1234",
                    "1234hello",
                    "12345hello",
                    "hello12345"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + isValid(s)));
    }
    static boolean isValid(String s) {
        return s.matches("^(?=(?:\\D*\\d){2})[a-zA-Z\\d]{9,}$");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
helloworld => false
hello => false
hello12world => true
12helloworld => true
helloworld12 => true
123456789 => true
hello1234 => true
1234hello => true
12345hello => true
hello12345 => true
```